# logout button in navbar spring using sitemesh

Tags: html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-security, sitemesh

I followed spring security tutorials but all of them are giving status of login in the page, not in navbar like usually websites do.
        I wanna show username in navbar after user logs in and logut button,
        I am using sitemesh and navbar is separate page, I have no idea how to show globally logout button,here is my navbar.jsp page.
    Thanks.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">                                   
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GSYS</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="<c:url value="/" />">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<c:url value="/resources" />">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<c:url value="/groups" />">Groups</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="<c:url value="/account/signup" />">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li ><a href="<c:url value="/" />">Sign Up</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>                           
          </div>
```